# add rel='nofollow' in haml javascript filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Im trying to add `rel='nofollow'` to the script tag for javascript. The purpose is to tell bots not to follow the link within the script tag. However, I am not sure how to do it.

The closest I got was putting it like this:

```
%script{rel='nofollow', type='text/javascript'}
  :cdata
    $.ajax({url: '/onepiece'});
```

But this throws a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error, because

```
<script rel="nofollow" type="text/javascript">
    <![CDATA[
```

is rendered. I think what should be rendered should be

```
<script rel="nofollow" type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
```

Is there another way to do this using haml?

Comment: That code won’t render anything, it will give you an ``undefined method `map' for "nofollow":String`` error.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5 the nofollow keyword can only be applied to `a` and `area` elements. (Source: [W3C recommendation on html5 links](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#link-type-nofollow)). Also, there is no `rel` attribute for `script` elements.

If the page you are looking to block is inside your domain, I'd suggest doing that [in robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) which should stop most bots from crawling the page.

Hope that helps!